# content length issue when upload file to api by PHP curl.

Tags: php, api, curl

I am using the following code for upload the file via api.
but i found that the file content type is wrong(just around 26 byte)after uploaded.
the content type will be the length of the $data_string. 
I tried to change the content length to filesize of the upload file. 
but after that the api is not working. is any coding i did wrong?

```
$data        = array("Content" => "file.wav"); //around 4mb
$data_string = json_encode($data);  
$ch          = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'URL');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
  'Content-type: audio/wav',                                                                           
  'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");

$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$data        = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

$data_string is a string formed by json encoding an array, which is having a pair of strings and hence it will be the size of that array not the size of file. I recommend u to use filesize() function if u r trying to find the size of file.

http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.filesize.php

*also check "$username:$password", if it is in the right form.